# Average of measures to re-calculate if a filter is applied - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have the following calculated measure:

[image]

I also have a series of drop-down filters, such as the name of the agent, report date on the page, etc.. I need to calculate the average of the measure which will be re-calculated if any filter is applied, e.g. a date period is selected or a name of the agent is picked, etc. I tried with

```
=averagex(values(date,date.[Month]), [% of requests (urgent and not-urgent]).
```

It doesn't work if the incomplete date range is selected, e.g. from the 5th of Jan till now or when the agent filter is applied. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the AVERAGEX function, it calculates the average of the criteria that will be recalculated in any filtering process that I create from the data I have.
At the same time, the data centered on the date that can be set in the slicer is being calculated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrMKF.png)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, jut tried but it looks like it calculated average for all possible combinations - the avg of... dropped to like 1%.